# Create new user loop

Tags: bash

I want to create a new user script that I can loop for creating a second or third.

So far I have something like this, but i'm stuck on the rest.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you want to create a new user (y/n): "
read createNewUser

while [[ createNewUser ]]; do
   echo "Enter username: "
   read username
   echo "Enter first name: "
   read firstname
   echo "Enter last name: "
   read lastname

   useradd -g staff -c "${firstname} ${lastname}" -s /bin/bash $username

   mkhomedir_helper $username

 done
```

Do I ask the question again before the done statement or can I include it at the top of the loop instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for the ***"Do you want to create a new user (y/n): "*** prompt and the input to be within the *while* conditional .

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ "$(read -p "Do you want to create a new user (y/n): " x; echo $x)" == "y" ]] ; do
   echo "Enter username: "
   read username
   echo "Enter first name: "
   read firstname
   echo "Enter last name: "
   read lastname

   useradd -g staff -c "${firstname} ${lastname}" -s /bin/bash $username

   mkhomedir_helper $username
done
```

This should ask you for confirmation before an iteration begins.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, when your current script says
   `while [[ createNewUser ]]`, it is essentially saying
   “while the constant string `createNewUser` is not an empty string”. 
   So your current script runs forever,
   even if you answer the question with **`no`**. 
   Since `createNewUser` is a variable,
   you need to reference it as `$createNewUser`.
2. As you speculated and [Jedi confirmed](https://superuser.com/q/1095849/354511#1095861),
   if you want your script to create a user
   and then ask whether you want to do another,
   you need it to ask you as part of the loop. 
   Here’s another way of doing that; I believe (IMHO) that
   this is a bit more straightforward than [Jedi’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1095849/354511#1095861):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   while read -p "Do you want to create a new user (y/n): " createNewUser  &&
         [[ "$createNewUser" == y* ]]
   do
       echo "Enter username: "
       read username
       echo "Enter first name: "
       read firstname
       echo "Enter last name: "
       read lastname

       useradd -g staff -c "$firstname $lastname" -s /bin/bash "$username"

       mkhomedir_helper "$username"
   done
   ```

   From the [POSIX Shell Command Language Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09),
   the format of the `while` loop is as follows:

   ```
   while compound-list-1
   do
       compound-list-2
   done
   ```

   i.e., you can have multiple statements between the `while` and the `do`. 
   (I guess Jedi is bending over backwards to do it with a single command.) 
   My approach splits the query and the test
   into two separate simple statements. 
   The loop will continue to run as long as the `read` succeeds
   **and** the user response (i.e., *your* response) begins with `y`
   (because the two statements are separated by `&&`).
3. As long as you’re using bash,
   and you’re using `[[`…`]]` (instead of `[`…`]`),
   and you’re using `==` (instead of `=`),
   the right side of the test can be a pattern,
   like the ones you use for pathname expansion (i.e., globs/wildcards). 
   By testing `[[ "$createNewUser" == y* ]]`,
   your script will accept any input beginning with `y`,
   such as `yes`, `yeah`, `yup` and `you bet!`

   Note that the `y*` *must **not*** be quoted,
   or else the script will accept only the literal string `y*`.
4. You should always quote your shell variable references
   (e.g., `"$username"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
   and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Strictly speaking,
   you might not *need* to in the `[[ "$createNewUser" == y* ]]` test
   (the first position in a `[[` test in bash is treated specially),
   but it’s generally recommended that you get into the habit
   of always doing it unless you have a real reason not to.
5. We quote variables
   to handle values that contain spaces and other special characters. 
   Your script would be better if you verified
   that `$username` contains only characters that are valid in usernames;
   otherwise, the `useradd` might fail. 
   (You might also want to check whether `useradd` fails by doing something like

   ```
       useradd -g staff -c "$firstname $lastname" -s /bin/bash "$username"  &&
       mkhomedir_helper "$username"
   ```

   or

   ```
       if useradd -g staff -c "$firstname $lastname" -s /bin/bash "$username"
       then
           mkhomedir_helper "$username"
       else
           echo "useradd failed"
       fi
   ```

   By extension, you might also want to test
   whether `mkhomedir_helper` succeeds or fails.)
6. You don’t need `{` and `}` in `"${firstname} ${lastname}"`. 
   See [Using single or double bracket in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/80216#286525)
   for a discussion of `[[`…`]]` vs. `[`…`]`
   and when you need to use `${variable_name}`.
7. You might want to test whether `firstname` or `lastname` is null. 
   For example, if you were creating an account for the musician Sting,
   and you entered `Sting` as his first name and nothing as his last name,
   his name would be saved as `Sting`   (with a space at the end). 
   Consider something like

   ```
       if [ "$firstname" = "" ]
       then
           fullname="$lastname"
       elif [ "$lastname" = ""]
       then
           fullname="$firstname"
       else
           fullname="$firstname $lastname"
       fi
       useradd -g staff -c "$fullname" -s /bin/bash "$username"
   ```

   Or you could just ask a single question for the user’s full name.
8. You might want to consider switching all your `read` statements
   to the `read -p` variety.